# ng v command giving error: 'The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object'

Tags: angular

Getting path error on running ng v command.

I expect ng v to return angular version, but I am getting the following error:

```
The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received 
type object
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type 
string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object
at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:785:3)
at VersionCommand.run 
(C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\version.js:48:19)
at C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:278:30
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:4:58)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: This won't fix your workstation's config, but a quick note: you must use `ng --version` or the alias `ng v`. https://angular.io/cli#command-overview Currently, you are trying to alias incorrectly when you use one dash and the alias name: `ng -v`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a "node_modules" folder in "c:\". I had the same problem. Fixed it by deleting "c:\node_modules".